# On selected radio button change text field type to numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **one text field** and  **two radio buttons**.

I want the following to happen

- `Option A` selected = **do nothing**
- `Option B` selected = **change the text input type to `number`**

I'm having a problem reverting the input type back to `text` when the user selection `Option A` after selecting `Option B`. The field type remains as `number`.

**How can I make this revert to the original state when `Option A` is reselected?**

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tk8efkn7/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='searchby']").live("change", function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "tag") {
            //clear the text field
             $('#textvalue').val("");

             if($('#c_tag').is(':checked')) {            
                $("#textvalue").keypress(function (e) {
//if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
                if (e.which != 8 && e.which !== 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
//display error message
                $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
                }
                });
            }
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == "name") {
            //clear the text field
            $('#textvalue').val("");          
        }
    }); 
});
```

> **Edit:**
>   The code above is uses `jQuery v1.6.3`.
>
> For `jQuery v1.7+`, Please change the following deprecated event: `.live()` to `.on()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove any keypress handlers from `#textvalue` using the [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function, ie.:

```
$('#textvalue').unbind("keypress");
```

Here's a [modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5fgm3xy/1/).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.